# How to use server side template in Kendo Grid for ASP.NET Core

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Telerik's UI for ASP.NET Core and I am trying to user server side template for Grid column like below

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridModel>()
    .Name("Grid")                    
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Template(@<text>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@item.ID"/>
                     </text>);
        col.Bound(p => p.Amount).Title("Amount").Format("{0:C}");
        col.Bound(p => p.DueDate).Title("Due Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");                        
    })
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable(sortable => sortable
    .AllowUnsort(true)
    .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(50)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
        })
        .Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetData", "MyController");
        })
    ).Deferred())
```

However, on this line `value="@item.ID"` VS 2017 throws error as

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate type

Answer (score 0):

Since your grid is *Ajax* bound and not *server* bound, you should use `ClientTemplate` instead. As per [API](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq):-

> If the Grid is Ajax-bound, use the ClientTemplate method. The value
>   should be a string, which represents a valid Kendo UI Template.

You need to use client template like this:-

```
col.Template(@<text></text>)
   .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value='#= data.ID #"/>");
```

Please Note: We need `Template` here only if you don't have any `Bound` column (as shown in API) otherwise you can use `Bound + ClientTemplate` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
col.Template("<input type='checkbox' value='#= data.ID #"/>");
```

This is the solution

Comment: Put the string from the cleinttemplate direct in the template